# Find the equation of both Tangent and Normal Line to "$y=3\cos(2x)$" at $x=\dfrac{\pi}{6}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Find the equation of both Tangent and Normal Line to "$y=3\cos(2x)$" at $x=\dfrac{\pi}{6}$.

I tell you what I did to find the equation of Normal Line. Firstly I let the equation equal $y=mx+c$ and find $m$. To find $m$ I took the derivative of the equation, then substitute in the value of $x$, then I did the inverse of the awnser. So I got the value of $m$. After that, to find $c$, I found the value of value of $y$ by putting the value of $x$ into the real equation $y=3\cos(2x)$ and put the value of $x, y$ in $y=mx+c$ but i couldn't get the right answer.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Can you [edit] your question to include your thoughts and efforts on this problem? What have you tried, and where are you having difficulty? This will help people write an appropriate answer the addresses your problem. Questions that include this information tend to have a much better response.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: For the tangent line, you use the equation $y - 3\cos(2\cdot \frac{\pi}{6}) = y'(\frac{\pi}{6})(x-\frac{\pi}{6})$, and for the normal line, the equation is:
$y - 3\cos(2\cdot \frac{\pi}{6}) = -\dfrac{1}{y'(\frac{\pi}{6})}(x-\frac{\pi}{6})$

Comment: thanks for the reply and i found tangent line but cannot find the normal line

Comment: Try the formula above if you can.